# Java - beginner code, adding fractions

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I have a school project due next week and I'm trying to crack the way to solve this question.
The problem was to develop a program that adds the fractions the user inputs until he types -1.

- the input will always be in pair and positive numbers.
- Must only use: int, for,while, if, scanner (so no break or arrays)
- Preferably with the use of GCD since it's required to println the
  reduced sum of fractions

So my questions are this:

- can I use a while loop until user types -1 using the scanner?
- Is it alright to use the 'while' to let a user type 'infinite' (I am aware that there is no such this in java) number of number until termination?
- in the code of the previous question I wrote the common factor for
  the equation, how do I write a common factor for an unknown number of
  variables

**Edit:**
here is my code, the problem is, it only runs for 4*n numbers, I need it to be able to run for 2*n numbers: ( like 2/4 or 2/4+1/3+1/2)

```
Scanner myScanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        int d;
        int m = a*d + b*c;
        int n = b*d;
        int r = m%n;

        while((a = myScanner.nextInt()) != -1)
        {
            b = myScanner.nextInt();
            c = myScanner.nextInt();
            d = myScanner.nextInt(); 
            while (r != 0) {
                m=n;
                n=r; 
                r = m%n;
            }
            m = (a*d + b*c)/n;
            n = (b*d)/n;

            System.out.println(m);
            System.out.println(n);

        }

}
```

Comment: You miss somewhere int userInput = 0; while(userInput != -1){ /*do stuff */ userInput = myScanner.nextInt();
}

Comment: To compute F1 + F2 + F3, you can start by computing F1 + F2, store the result (let's name it Fcurrent), then compute Fcurrent + F3. So you always add two fraction, not an infinite number of them. If you need to add F4, then you can store the result of Fcurrent + F3 in Fcurrent again, and then compute Fcurrent + F4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A.

It is possible to keep reading input from a scanner until a defined message (in this case pairs of numbers until `-1` is entered)

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int num1;
int num2;

while((num1 = scanner.nextInt()) != -1)
{
    num2 = scanner.nextInt();
    //do stuff with num1 and num2
}
```

---

## B.

The whole point of **A.** is to allow variable amounts of input from the user, so unless you have a reason for a hard limit, it should in theory take infinite input

---

## C.

Instead of trying to compute the common factor before you have any numbers, it's easier to compute the common factor as you get the numbers

```
int newNumerator = numerator1 * denominator2 + numerator2 * denominator1;
int newDenominator = denominator1 * denominator2;
```

Keeping track of the current numerator and denominator, updating as you get more pairs

This can then have **A.** be applied to it for infinite input

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int numerator = 0;
int denominator = 0;
int tempNumer = 0;
int tempDenom = 0;

if((numerator = scanner.nextInt()) != -1)
{
    denominator = scanner.nextInt();
    while((tempNumer = scanner.nextInt()) != -1)
    {
        tempDenom = scanner.nextInt();
        numerator = numerator * tempDenom + tempNumer * denominator;
        denominator = denominator * tempDenom;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I enter the common factor 
int m = a*d + b*c;
        int n = b*d;     if the numbers are in a loop and there is only 1 fraction? the solution here is counting on 4 numbers

Comment: @Shira edited with an example of parts A and C combined

Comment: thank you! I entered the gcd and got the fractions however now it only lets me enter 2 pairs of numbers(so 4 numbers, 8 and so on). what can I do to let the user type one pair? (2 numbers, 6 numbers)

Comment: @Shira What is your input/output?

Comment: if there are 6 number (or any 2*n and not 4*n), there is no output. it asks me to add more numbers

Comment: @Shira I get the correct expected output (56/64=0.875) when I add 1/8, 1/4, and 1/2.  To test I used `Scanner scanner = new Scanner("1 8 1 4 1 2 -1");`.  What input are you using?  Are you entering -1?

Comment: 1 2 1 3 1 4 -1. it has also to be the the reduced form of the fraction

Comment: @Shira I tested with `Scanner scanner = new Scanner("1 2 1 3 1 4 -1");` and got the expected result (26/24=1.0833...).  To reduce the fraction, try using the code you already have, `int r = m%n; while{...}` calculates the greatest common factor, and can be used to simplify the calculated `numerator` and `denominator`